# creating hash table for storing value of some pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, hash

I want to create hash table for storing pointer (i.e. memory location of some node).

For this I have made an array of `double` data type (because double and pointer both has same size on my system). And I am storing address into elements of array. But its giving me error.

Code:

```
struct node* temp = head;
int k = 0;
while (temp->next)
{
     addresses[k++] = (double)temp; // error is here.
     temp = temp->next;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
addresses[k++] = (double)temp;
```

I think typecasting should the problem. The error message is: `pointer value used where a floating point value was expected`

Again, there would be error when I would be fetching array element and storing in some pointer to node.

Thus, how should I create hash table for storing pointers?

Comment: That is so wrong, using a `double` as a pointer! It really breaks *strict aliasing*. If you want a generic pointer in C then us `void*`. In C++ you don't need to create a hash table, [because it already has one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Are you really trying to cast a `struct node*` to `double`?

Comment: C (and thus C++) has `intptr_t` for these exceptional cases where you want to store a pointer in an integer type.  At least this is guaranteed to have the same size as a pointer.

Comment: Do you have to create your own hash table? Why don't you use unordered set instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to typecast the pointer. Just make "addresses" an array of pointers to the node structure. Here's the code:

```
struct node* addresses[some_size];
struct node* temp = head;
int k = 0;
while (temp->next)
{
     addresses[k++] = temp; //no typecasting
     temp = temp->next;
}
```